# no matching index found. recommended index is

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I am really confused by how to solve this issue.
I tried all the answers I could find from googling this issue. 
I got this error, as many other people got.

no matching index found. recommended index is:\n- kind: Task\n  ancestor: yes\n  properties:\n  - name: appName\n  - name: RequestTime\n    direction: desc\n\nThe suggested index for this query is:\n    \n        \n        \n    \n\n"

After that I followed this error message and create a datastore-indexes.xml like this:

```
<datastore-index source="manual" ancestor="true" kind="Task">
  <property direction="asc" name="appName"/>
  <property direction="desc" name="RequestTime"/>
</datastore-index>

<datastore-index source="manual" ancestor="true" kind="ServerLogFile">
    <property direction="desc" name="LastDate"/>
</datastore-index>
```

But I am still getting the same error. By checking cloud console, the indexes are created and are all in serving state on app engine side.
Can someone give me some suggestions what else I can do to solve this issue?

Comment: Double-check that the serving indexes exactly match the definitions (property order matters) - it's easy to miss small differences. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318996/google-datastore-composite-index-issue

Comment: Can you confirm whether Dan's comment helped you to solve the issue? If not, could you provide us the Cloud Datastore entities and query that you are using.