# Error: FAILED_PRECONDITION: no matching index found. recommended index is:

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore, google-query-language

So I'm trying to run a query on Google Cloud's datastore as such:

```
let query = datastore.createQuery(dataType)
    .select(["id", "version", "lm", "name"])
    .filter("owner", "=", request.params.owner)
    .filter("lm", ">=", request.query.date_start)
    .groupBy(["lm"])
    .order("lm")
```

Yet I run into an error stating that

```
no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: Entry
  properties:
  - name: lm
  - name: id
  - name: name
  - name: version
```

When I run the query with `id` instead of `lm` for all the methods I run into no errors. 
Is this because in my `index.yaml` file I  have the index as such: ?

```
- kind: Entry
  properties:
  - name: id
  - name: version
  - name: lm
  - name: name
```

Must I actually create a new index with the recommended ordering? Or is there a way I can do this without having to make another index? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to create a new index, the existing one you showed is **not** equivalent, so it can't be used for your query - the property order matters (at least for the inequality filters and sorting). See related [Google Datastore Composite index issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318996/google-datastore-composite-index-issue)